# Objective-c parse api response special characters

Tags: objective-c, encoding, special-characters, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

Im making a request to an API, this is the NSData receiving the return:

```
{"word":"Ma\u00f1ana reposado"}
```

What im trying to do its to display a label with this data, but when i parse it with:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:1 error:&error];
```

The NSString* inside [json ObjectForKey:@"word"] = "Ma?ana reposado"

How is the proper way to un-encode the NSData?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not null-terminated, use initWithData:[encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSUTF8StringEncoding)

```
  NSString* yourNSString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If the data is null-terminated, use stringWithUTF8String: to avoid the extra \0 (NUL terminator) at the end

```
  NSString* yourNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
```

Comment: I Tried it, and the result was "Ma\u00f1ana reposado"

Comment: I tried it now, they are unicode (LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE) the format is correct, put them on a UILabel or something and they'll appear as you expect. I tried and got the output: Mañana reposado